# PHP mailer sending email SMTP with wamp error (10061)

Tags: php, smtp, wamp, phpmailer

I am trying to send email/SMTP with PHP from my localhost with WAMP
but it's giving me the following error:

**SMTP -> ERROR: Failed to connect to server: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
 (10061)**

here is my code:

```
  require_once("./PHPMailer_5.2.4/class.phpmailer.php");
// The message
$message = "hello there!";

$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();; // send via SMTP
$mail->Mailer = 'smtp';
$mail->SMTPDebug=4;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // turn on SMTP authentication
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com'; // "ssl://smtp.gmail.com" didn't worked
//$mail->Port = 465;
// $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';

// or try these settings (worked on XAMPP and WAMP):
 $mail->Port = 587;
 $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';

$mail->Username = "myemailu@gmail.com"; // SMTP username
$mail->Password = "mypass****"; // SMTP password
$webmaster_email = "myemail@doamin.com"; //Reply to this email ID
$email="ohermail@yahoo.com"; // Recipients email ID
$name="name"; // Recipient's name
$mail->From = $webmaster_email;
$mail->FromName = "Webmaster";
$mail->AddAddress($email,$name);
$mail->AddReplyTo($webmaster_email,"Webmaster");
$mail->WordWrap = 50; // set word wrap
$mail->IsHTML(true); // send as HTML
$mail->Subject = "This is the subject";
$mail->Body = "Hi,
This is the HTML BODY "; //HTML Body
$mail->AltBody = "This is the body when user views in plain text format"; //Text Body
if(!$mail->Send())
{
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
else
{
    echo "Message has been sent";
}
```

Comment: please provide your code.

Comment: you can not send mail from your local server and for that either you have to use a smtp server with a username and password and pass that credentials in your code or till then you can try to send mail using google smpt service using your google credentials.

Comment: You're using an old and buggy example - I suggest you start again using [an up to date one](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/gmail.phps), and update to a recent PHPMailer while you're at it. You should not set `Mailer` - `isSMTP()` does that for you, correctly. Next, you should [read the documentation](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting) on this precise subject.